# How to passing string to ffmpeg correctly?

Tags: c#, string, ffmpeg, process, escaping

I would like to pass this string to ffmpeg through the process function. I launched the program but ffmpeg does not run it. where did I go wrong?? Maybe the escape sequenze?

```
string templateMergingIntroOutro = " -i \"" + "{0}" + "\" -i \"" + "{1}" + "\" -i \"" + "{2}" + "\" -filter_complex “[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]” -map “[v]” -map “[a]” \"" + "{3}";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
“[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]” -map “[v]” -map “[a]”
```

Looks like you put this together in Microsoft Word. Use straight quotes (`"`) for code.